# How can I apply Flask admin filter function at front?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

My site needs a filter function, support multiple params filter.

I'm new to Python, don't know how to do it.
I only have a single params filter function, I wrote a dump code like this, and I know it's a dump but better than nothing..

```
@front_bp.route('/<any(district,rooms,price,type):url_path>/<keyword>/<int:page>/')
def houses_list(url_path,keyword,page = 1):
if url_path == 'district':
    result = {
        'keyword':keyword,
        'url_path':url_path,
        'houses': Home.query.filter(Home.house_district == keyword,Home.house_status == None).order_by(Home.id.desc()).paginate(page,16, False)
    }
    return render_template('house.html',**result)

elif url_path == 'price':
    pricerange = keyword.split('-')

    result = {
        'keyword': keyword,
        'url_path': url_path,
        'houses': Home.query.filter(Home.rental_price > pricerange[0],Home.rental_price <= pricerange[1], Home.house_status == None).order_by(Home.id.desc()).paginate(page, 16, False)
    }
    return render_template('house.html', **result)

elif url_path == 'rooms':
    roomsrange =[int(keyword)-1,int(keyword)]
    result = {
        'keyword': keyword,
        'url_path': url_path,
        'houses': Home.query.filter(Home.house_rooms > roomsrange[0],Home.house_rooms<= roomsrange[1],Home.house_status == None).order_by(Home.id.desc()).paginate(page, 16, False)
    }
    return render_template('house.html',**result)

elif url_path == 'type':
    result = {
        'keyword': keyword,
        'url_path': url_path,
        'houses': Home.query.filter(Home.house_type == keyword,Home.house_status == None).order_by(Home.id.desc()).paginate(page, 16, False)
    }
    return render_template('house.html',**result)
```

I noticed Flask admin have a multiple params filter on the backend. 
My question is How can I use it on the front?  how to render with jinja theme?

or You guys have a better solution or module?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should register some blueprints with url_prefix, like rooms_bp, price_bp, rather than a front_bp to cover all contents of your web. You could learn more about [blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprints).

```
rooms_page = Blueprint('rooms_page', __name__, template_folder='templates', url_prefix='/rooms')
```

After that, you could pass some parameters to jinja to render a template and the parameters could be used like in python according to the [Jinja2 Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/).

```
{% if houses %}
 <div>
 ...
 </div>
{% endif %}
```

Finally, if you really has many dynamic contents in your pages, a restful api using flask_restful module is necessary.

```
api_page = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
```

Comment: hi LNT, thanks for your answer, I know what you mean, But my real question is how to make that "multiple params filter." function..

Comment: Replace "return render_template('house.html',**result)" to "return render_template('house.html', result=result)". Then you can use result parameter in "'house.html'" like {% if result['keyword'] == something %} {% 
endif %}